# DataTables function- table.row.add , not working with button inside the table (javascript)

Tags: javascript, datatable, datatables

I'm using DataTables library for creating table with "download" button.

At the first row the button is working, but at the rest of the rows is not working (I'm using loop to enter the data to the table).

what am i doing wrong?

JS Code:

```
snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
 var childData = childSnapshot.val();
 number = childData.Number;
 table.row.add( [
       number,
       "<button id='script'>Download Files</button>"
    ] ).draw( false );
 button = document.getElementById('script');
 button.onclick = function(){ myScript(number)};
});
```

Comment: Please also post the HTML code and the complete JS code for the DataTable implementation. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You create many buttons with the same id, so `document.getElementById('script');` will always return the same first element with this id.

You can try something like this:

```js
snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot, i) {
 var childData = childSnapshot.val();
 number = childData.Number;
 table.row.add( [
       number,
       `<button id='script${i}'>Download Files</button>`
    ] ).draw( false );
 button = document.getElementById(`script${i}`);
 button.onclick = function(){ myScript(number)};
});
```